# What is the difference between get_post_permalink and get_permalink?

Tags: permalinks

I've read the documentation on [`get_post_permalink()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_permalink/) and [`get_permalink()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_permalink/) and don't understand the difference between the two. It might be because I don't understand the purpose of the `$leavename` and `$sample` parameters. Can anyone explain those, and when one function would be more useful than the other? Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

The [`get_post_permalink()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_permalink/) funciton fetches the link to a post depending on its "permanent" link plus your custom rewrite rules that changes `?p=123` into for e.g. `my-beautiful-sunday-diary`. The [`get_permalink()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_permalink/) function is more "basic" but as well more versatile in what it does: For a `post_type` of

- `page`, it uses `get_page_link()`
- `attachment`, it uses `get_attachment_link()`
- `post`, it uses `get_post_link()`

It also handles the display of `term`s like `category` and date permalinks. At the end, it either replaces the "pretty" link in your `home_url()` or just returns the raw link if no custom rewrite rules were assigned. Finally it attaches a generic filter:

```
/**
 * Filters the permalink for a post.
 *
 * Only applies to posts with post_type of 'post'.
 *
 * @since 1.5.0
 *
 * @param string  $permalink The post's permalink.
 * @param WP_Post $post      The post in question.
 * @param bool    $leavename Whether to keep the post name.
 */
return apply_filters( 'post_link', $permalink, $post, $leavename );
```

Hope that clarifies the topic.

ProTip: If you need to change peramlinks in a plugin, go with the specific filters inside `get_attachment_link()`, `get_post_link()`, etc. Only if you are either working on a single site and are not planning to distribute your code or if you are writing a plugin targetting only rewrite stuff, then go with the generic filter above. Else you will nuke every theme authors efforts and start a callback priority race.

Answer (score 2):

Someone else will certainly explain better than me. As I only use `get_permalink()`

They are mostly similar as they both return the post permalink, `get_permalink` use `get_post_permalink` (for post_types) and can be filter. It will also be use to retrieve a page link, attachment... where `get_post_permalink` seems to be dedicated to post_types.

EDIT:

About the use of `$leavename`, it's look like there is no need for a front-end  (and even in the back-end) use as it return the permastructure slug, according to the post type of the link.

```
 echo get_permalink(123, true);
```

Return the rewrite schema for the link, that could be use

A post:

```
 http://example.com/%postname%/
```

A product:

```
 http://example.com/%product%/
```

$leavename is use in the get_permalink() in the $rewritecode array and put as first paramater in the function line 221

```
$permalink = home_url( str_replace($rewritecode, $rewritereplace, $permalink) );
```

It can be usefull to discover the rewrite slug for a link for a developper (but I think there a better way to do this)

Hope someone will give more details.

Comment: Thanks! I'm still not really clear on this though. Have you ever used $leavename to change the permalink structure? Why and how would one do that? And do you mean that get_post_permalink() is used to retrieve archives, or are you referring to get_permalink() there? I've never seen get_post_permalink() used until today when I ran across it being used exactly like get_permalink() so I'm not clear on the difference.

Comment: I'm talking about get_permalink, you have it in the source, it retrieve author page, categories etc... It will do more than get_post_permalink. Get_permalink is a template function if I'm not mistaken, and is powerfull.

Comment: Understood, I'm just not getting when we'd ever need to or want to use get_post_permalink() - can you give a code example? And do you know what $leavename and $sample do? I've only ever used get_permalink() as well :-)

Comment: `$leavename` is used in admin, to get the permalink structure so that it can generate the interface that lets you edit a post's slug.